/scan range[] and intensity[] arrays all 0, but data is visualized in RVIZ
I am using a Turtlebot3 with ROS2 Humble, which I initialized with the command
ros2 launch turtlebot3_bringup robot.launch.py

This starts outputting the Lidar data to the /scan topic. When I try to see the data using
ros2 topic echo /scan

I get data that makes sense for all fields, except "ranges" and "intensities", which are all 0.

But, when I run basic rviz2 with command
ros2 launch turtlebot3_bringup rviz2.launch.py

I can see that I am getting laser scan data as can be shown from the wall I put up in front of my robot. Is there any reason why I would not be able to seen my ranges with ros2 topic echo /scan, but I can still see the data when I subscribe to the topic via rviz?


By default, the output of ros2 topic echo is truncated. To see all the values you can use the flag --full-length. Check with this output all the values (you can also redirect the output to a file instead of scrolling in the terminal).
According to the definition of the LaserScan message, the values smaller than the range_min and greater than the range_max should be discarded. In rviz, all the values are read and the 0.0 are discarded because they are smaller than range_min, that is 0.119 m. That is the reason why you only see points that "make sense", the points that correspond to the wall measure that lie within the limits of range_min and range_max.

This is the correct answer. I added the --full-length flag, and I can see the rest of the ranges that are non-zero.
